# Woocommerce - Change single product per row to multiple (Mobile Responsive)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, woocommerce

I'm trying to get woocommerce to display 2 or 3 (I would like to test both as i'm not sure which will suit best) products within a row instead of the default 1 when the screen size is smaller than 480px(mobile).

How it currently looks; http://prnt.sc/e0m1l7

The site: http://historicmotorsporttransmissions.com/shop/

I've been searching around for a plugin to help but I think css would do the job. All the code snippets around seem to be based on a certain theme and just cant get them working.

Could someone lend a hand please? 
Many thanks -Lewis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to try this within your CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px){
  .woocommerce .products li.product {
      width: 50% !important;
  }
}
```

Change to 33.33% if you would like to display 3.